# How to convert numeric date variable into quarterly date?

Tags: r, date

I have a panel dataset, and the first column of which is the date in the format Year-quarter in Stata, like the following:

```
quarter id
1993q1  1
1993q2  1
1993q3  1
1993q4  1
1994q1  1
1994q2  1
1994q3  1
1994q4  1
1995q1  1
1995q2  1
1995q3  1
1995q4  1
```

I have imported the dataset from Stata into R, but I don't know how to convert this to the Date format using as.Date function.(I have just started learning R) The Date looks like the following in **R**:

```
quarter
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
```

**So my question:** is there a built-in way to import quarterly data in the format I have in Stata, and if not, how can I convert this numeric date into quarterly in R? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as.yearqtr` from the `zoo` package.
For the string format:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearqtr("1993q1",format="%Yq%q")
#[1] "1993 Q1"
```

For the number format:

```
#origin seems to be 1958 Q4
start_val=1958.75
#137 is the first value in your list
as.yearqtr(start_val+137/4)
#[1] "1993 Q1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(zoo)
quarter <- c("1993q1", "1993q2")
as.yearqtr(quarter)
## [1] "1993 Q1" "1993 Q2"
```

Also note the percent codes in `?strftime` and in `?as.yearqtr`

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: It's not.  I didn't know the other answer had posted.  I'm brand new here so trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @cryo111 Just to confirm that: this code worked out:  `start_val=1958.75    q<-as.yearqtr(start_val+ quarter/4)`

Comment: This answer uses the fact that the default format works with as.yearqtr so it is slightly simpler.